# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I understand that this question has been asked many times but the error with 
connection is giving me a hard time.

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

I'm trying to search for a phone number from a table. I have tried almost all the solutions given in other threads but couldn't seem to figure out how to rectify the error. I have to associate command with sqlconnection but i couldn't do that.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);

using( SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand() )
{
conn.Open();

cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.CommandText = "SearchName";
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter();
p1.ParameterName = "@Name";//Stored Proc
p1.Value = SearchbyName.Name;
cmd1.Parameters.Add(p1);

using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
 if (dr.Read())
 {
   while (dr.Read())
   {
   Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + " " + dr[1]);
   }
   SearchExit();
   }
 else
   {
   Console.WriteLine("No contact found with name {0}", SearchbyName.Name);
   }

   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd1.Connection = conn;
   conn.Close();
   SearchExit();
   }
 }
```

Comment: There's no need to call `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` as well as `cmd1.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Also. you're calling `dr.Read()` **twice**. once in an `if` and once in a `while` which means you skip the first result, as [Read advances to the next record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cmd1.Connection = conn;
```

should be right after you instance it, or even better, pass the conn object in the SqlCommand constructor.

Comment: I apologize but can you be a little more specific please. @Pedro Luz

Comment: @ananthreddy assign the connection to the command object **before** calling `cmd1.ExecuteReader()`, as otherwise it doesn't know what connection to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Connection property after executing the query:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
// More code here
cmd1.Connection = conn;
```

Set 
    cmd1.Connection = conn; 
before 
    cmd1.ExecuteReader.